# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Tags: gmail, jira, x509, keytool

I am trying to import Gmails smtp certificate for use with Jira, but I get this error when importing using Javas keytool.

I used openssl to get the certificate, everything between ----Begin Certificate---- and ----End Certificate---- (inclusive).  I also attempted to create an x.509 certificate using Windows Certificate Manager, but still get this error.  I have verified that there are no extra whitespaces in the file.

I have seen many people with this problem online, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`openssl x509 -outform der -in foo.pem -out foo.der`

Then use the DER-encoded output certificate.

Comment: I was really hoping this would work, but I jut keep getting the same error.  Here is what I'm doing exactly.

    openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465

I copy that to a file called gmail.pem

    openssl x509 -outform der -in gmail.pem -out gmail.der

    keytool -import -file pathTo/gmail.der -keystore pathTo/cacerts

Comment: This actually did work, I forgot the argument -trustcacerts when using keytool.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @dbbooh01 the reason this probably worked is because `-trustcacerts` imports the standard root CAs from the distributed cacerts file. This would include the root CAs that were in the trust chain for Gmail.

Comment: @dbbooh01 : will you give me whole command you have entered. i have also write `x509 -outform der -in gmail.pem -out gmail.der` but it doesn't generate file gamil.der. where it generate file gmail.der ?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is correct but be sure to INCLUDE the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` in the copy/paste.
This command will then work:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in gmail.pem -out gmail.der
```

and then you do:

```
sudo keytool -import -file gmail.der -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts
```

Comment: Yepp, this was the cause of my problem too

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, openssl didn't work for me.

> unable to load certificate 2740:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:./crypto/as n1/tasn_dec.c:1294:
>   2740:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested
>   asn1 error:./ crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:380:Type=X509_CINF
>   2740:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 e
>   rror:./crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:749:Field=cert_info, Type=X509
>   2740:error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1
>   lib:./crypto/pem/pem_oth .c:83:

Used this knowledge base and success followed.

https://knowledge.verisign.ch/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=SO18659&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1343045026667