# Input not an X.509 certificate Not working even after converting to DER

Tags: keytool

First of all I have already seen the post [keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449597/keytool-error-java-lang-exception-input-not-an-x-509-certificate). I am unable to apply the same solution in my situation thats why I am posting this thread. When I tried to import my PEM file into keytoo it said that

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

When I tried to use openssl to connect to my server having -CAfile option as this PEM file. it connected suxxessfully.

I converted the PEM file into DER file as suggested in the above post using,

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in foo.pem -out foo.der
```

I imported the der file successfully into keytool. But when I try to connect to the server which was connectable using PEM file in openSSL, I am unable to connect. It is throwing

at

```
javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www.protocol.https.b.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www.protocol.http.cb.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www.protocol.http.cb.p(Unknown Source)
```

I have created a new thread to get immediate attention from you guys as it is so urgent fo rme. Kindly help.

Comment: the PEM file contains closer to 160 certificates in it

Answer (score 0):

keytool only supports single certificate PEM files. They can not include anything outside of the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` brackets.

When using multipart PEM files, such as ca-bundle.crt, you will need to extract each certificate into a separate file. It's not necessary to convert them to DER before importing using keytool

You could also use my tool, https://code.google.com/p/java-keyutil/, which can import multipart PEM files straight into JKS files.